# What is structure of a selector to define item

Tags: android, xml

why we define this item in last

```
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/twitter_im_edittext_normal" />
```

in a selector like this

```
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
           <item android:state_window_focused="false" 
                 android:state_enabled="true"
                 android:drawable="@drawable/twitter_im_edittext_normal" />
           <item android:state_window_focused="false" 
                  android:state_enabled="false"
                  android:drawable="@drawable/twitter_im_edittext_normal" />
           <item android:state_pressed="true" 
                 android:drawable="@drawable/twitter_im_edittext_normal" />
           <item android:state_enabled="true" 
                 android:state_focused="true"    
                 android:drawable="@drawable/twitter_im_edittext_focused" />
           <item android:state_enabled="true" 
                 android:drawable="@drawable/twitter_im_edittext_normal" />
           <item android:state_focused="true" 
                 android:drawable="@drawable/twitter_im_edittext_focused" />
           <item android:drawable="@drawable/twitter_im_edittext_normal" />
     </selector>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See at the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList)

> During each state change, the state list is traversed top to bottom and the first item that matches the current state is used—the selection is not based on the "best match," but simply the first item that meets the minimum criteria of the state.

Answer (score 0):

Think of a selector as a `switch` case. The statement are verified in the order they are listed, so the last one is your `default:` clause. In case your view doesn't match any of the conditions, it will default to

`<item android:drawable="@drawable/twitter_im_edittext_normal" />`